# Cannot resolve symbol Val and as

Tags: java, android, biometrics

When I use this code:

```
  val km = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager;
```

I get the same error code cannot resolve symbol for val and as.

Comment: What `val` is supposed to represent here? Is it some type which you created but forgot to import it, or maybe you wanted to use `var` instead of `val`?

Comment: Also `as KeyguardManager` doesn't look like `java` syntax. Are you sure you tagged your question correctly?

Comment: That is Kotlin syntax, not Java. If you are trying to use this in Java, you will need to rewrite it in Java.

Comment: You're trying to use Kotlin on a java project

Comment: I am using val along with  val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.screen_lock_title))

Comment: This is  what your Java code should look like : KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

Comment: "I am using val along with `val biometricPrompt = ...`" but what you are showing isn't Java, but as others pointed Kotlin. Those languages are not the same and their syntax is different. Is your question "how to convert that code to Java?" or maybe something else, like "how to set my project to Kotlin?" (since that seems to be what you are writing, but error message suggests you are compiling it using Java instead)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using kotlin based keyword 'val' which is unavailable in the context of java.

use the following to resolve it:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Nit: should be `final` to match `val`

Answer (score -1):

Val ValidMobileNumber=" 0123456789"
Val ValidPassword=" thanos"
Getting and error in android app development